# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord: how should I store a state of the object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, state

I have a User model, which has a state. The state can be either of these: ['unverified', 'active', 'deleted']

What is the best way to store the state of the object in the database?

Should I create three boolean fields? That would not make a lot of sense, since I might want to extend the number of states easily and only one state can be 'true' at the same time.

Should I use the [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) gem just for simple switching of constant values?

Or is there any other common way, best practice, or a simple gem for this kind of job?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A very simple solution I've used for this:

In your migration

```
add_column :users, :state, :string
```

In your model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  STATES = %w{ unverified active deleted }

  STATES.each do |state|
    define_method("#{state}?") do
      self.state == state
    end

    define_method("#{state}!") do
      self.update_attribute(:state, state)
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can call

```
@user.active? # => returns true/false
```

Or

```
@user.active! # => sets the users state to active
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Rails3 with MySQL database You can use [enum_column](https://github.com/electronick/enum_column). It provides an `:enum` column when to be used in migrations as well as a validation method. It also provides an enum_select view helper.

Answer (score 1):

I would leave it as nil, 'active', 'deleted'. If you wanted to have additional process hooks when the state is toggled, like emails sent out, then the state_machine gem would be useful. Also, if you wanted to have additional analytics like when somebody went from unverified to active, might be useful to have 'active_on_date' and store that as a datetime when the transition happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an enumerated type to store the state as a simple integer. I usually use the [active_enum](https://github.com/adzap/active_enum) gem to make this simple. It would look something like this

```
class User

  # An enumerated type representing the current state of the user
  enumerate :state do
    value name: "unverified"
    value name: "active"
    value name: "deleted"
  end

end
```

This will allow you to check the state in the following way

```
# check if active
user.state?(:active)
```

Just make sure you have an integer field named `state` (or whatever you want to call the enumerated type) in the `User` table.

See the [gem documentation](https://github.com/adzap/active_enum) for more details.

Comment: I really like this implementation, except that the IDs don't get stored in the database with referential integrity.

Comment: That is a good point. This would be true of any solution except for one which implements a ```State``` model, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use boolean fields.

If the names of states are like a "key" and are unlikely to change, you can just store them as text fields in the database.  Simply add a migration with

```
add_column :users, :state, :string
```

When you save your object, it will take user.state and store the symbol as a string of "unverified", "active", etc.

If the states are likely to get renamed at some point, then you can put them into their own table and make their own activerecord model for them instead of using a symbol.  do a

```
rails g model State name:string
```

rails will create a model file and migration for them.  Then alter the migration with this:

```
add_column :users, :state_id, :integer
```

You can populate the list of states with unverified, active, etc. either directly in sql or through a seed or the existing migration.  You can also create a foreign key between them if desired.

Then in your code, to set the state, you would use this:

```
user.state = State.find_by_name(:unverified)
```

Comment: Are you sure you would want to store the `state` column as `text`? It seems like it'd be better as a `string`.

Comment: this is suuuper late, but what is the benefit of doing this one way over the other? in other words, why create a model called `State` that handles the state of other objects, when i could just add `:state` as a string to my model? i know you propose one over the other in case states get renamed, but i'm not entirely sure what you mean by "renamed".